# Como recuperar valores de campos carregados com jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

Olá, recentemente deparei-me com um problema ao carregar conteúdos de div dinamicamente utilizando jQuery, mas acontece que quando carrego o conteúdo para essa div, não consigo recuperar os valores que são enviados dela.

O conteúdo carregado na div é um formulário, que quando clicado o botão "adicionar", ele carrega uma outra função no evento "onclick" desse mesmo botão, mas quando clico nesse botão a div retorna ao valor definido no default do switch e não carrega a função do evento colocado no botão.

Um dos formulários carregados nessa div é o de adição de produtos:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="produto"/>
<input type="number" name="preco"/>
<textarea name="descricao"></textarea>
<select name="categoria">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<button onclick="add()">Adicionar</button>
```

Por exemplo, ao accionar o botão "Adicionar", caso a função add() fosse executada sem erro, que fosse exibida uma mensagem na div "staus" e se mantivesse na mesma pagina em vez do retorno a página padrão

OBS: na função add() recolhe-se os dados vindos do formulário. Parte do script que trata desse formulário:

```
produto = $('input[name=xxx]').val();
$.post('adicionar.php',{produto:produto},function(i){$('#staus').html(i)});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xb576/1/

Comment: pode dar um exemplo do html que é carregado para dentro da div?

Comment: O exemplo encontra-se disponível desde que eu publiquei a pergunta, no final da pergunta.

Comment: Edilson, o que eu queria ver é o conteúdo que você vai buscar dinamicamente. O Formulário e o resto do conteudo que é carregado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** a div `#staus` está dentro do elemento `#direita` que é o target do método `load`, e portanto, será substituida pelo `form` que está vindo do servidor. Por isso, ao clicar no botão, a div `#status` não vai mais existir, pois ela foi apagada da página.

### `load` é assíncrono

O método `load` do jquery é assíncrono. Para ter acesso aos elementos trazidos pelo método `load` do jquery, você deve adicionar uma função de callback para quando o request estiver pronto:

```
$('#direita').load("url", 
     function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
         if (textStatus == "success") {
             // o request funcionou e os elementos já devem estar disponíveis
             // aqui você pode associar eventos aos elementos trazidos via AJAX
         }
         if (textStatus == "error") {
             // o request não funcionou, você terá de informar o usuário de que
             // algo deu errado
         }
     }
```

### Outras observações no seu código

O `case` do `switch` se faz colocando apenas o valor a ser comparado, e não fazendo uma atribuição no `case`.

```
switch(mostrar){
    case 'add': // errado: case mostrar = 'add' 
        break;
    case 'editar': // errado: case mostrar = 'editar' 
        break;
    default:
}
```

Comment: Ignorando o switch, e passando a parte em que eu não consigo pegar o valor dos selectores carregados nessa div *-*, porque o switch ainda assim funciona, embora eu tenha passado um argumento a mais a condição continua correcta

Comment: Está bem, de momento estou no linux, mas testarei o código assim que possível, para já obrigado

Comment: Não funcionou, faz a mesma coisa que o meu script fazia :s

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque ao delegar o evento ao botão, este ainda não existe no DOM. Para que o evento funcione com um elemento que ainda será carregado no DOM, você pode delegar o evento para um elemento pai que já exista e adicionar um filtro para o seletor realmente desejado.

**Exemplo:**

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(event) {

    // 

});
```

Sendo que `$(document)` é o elemento para qual o evento é delegado, e `'button'` o filtro que corresponde a um possível elemento que já existe ou surgirá dentro de `$(document)`.

Comment: Só para esclarecer, o meu problema não é simplesmente o evento, porque eu não consigo sequer pegar os valores dentro dessa mesma div, e o meu objectivo é pegar os valores do formulário na div. Tipo imprimir um alert contento o valor do input nessa div por exemplo.